# Finding the neighbors of 2D array

Tags: java, algorithm, grid, 2d, nearest-neighbor

I've a 2D grid of 75rows by 75 cols, I draw symbols of 2 colors (red and blue) on users clicks, it works fine but I'm stuck on a major problem I want to find the neighbor of those symbols: Example when the user click on a cell, it prints a symbol (oval) now I want that click also checks in its neighbors if the cell are occupied or empty, if occupied, by which symbol.

I found the algorithm below which seems to fit the need, but can't figure out how to adapt to my code:

```
private static int[][] array = new int[3][3];

    private static void initialiseArray() {
        int counter = 1;
        for (int row = ; row < 3; row++) {
            for (int col = ; col < 3; col++) {
                array[row][col] = counter;
                counter++;
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        initialiseArray();
        for (int row = ; row < 3; row++) {
            for (int col = ; col < 3; col++) {
                System.out.print(array[row][col]);
                if( col == 2 ){
                    System.out.println("\n");
                }
            }
        }
        neighbours();
    }

    public static void neighbours(){  
        int posX = 2;
        int posY = 2;

        for( int row = posX - 1; row <= posX + 1; row++){
            for(int col =  posY -1;  col <= posY + 1; col++){
                if( !(posX == row &&  posY == col) && row >= && col >= && row < 3 && col < 3 ){
                    System.out.println(array[row][col]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is my code, I need you help me solve this. Sorry bothering you.

```
public final class Pha extends JFrame {

    public static int ROWS = 75; 
    public static int COLS = 75;


    public static int cellSize = 15; 
    public static int canvasWidth = cellSize * COLS + (ROWS *4) ;
    public static int canvasHeight = cellSize * ROWS ;
    public static int gridWidth = 1;
    public static int halfGridWidth = gridWidth / 2;


    public static int cellPadding = cellSize / 5;
    public static int symbolSize = cellSize - cellPadding * 2; 
    public static int symbolStrokeWidth = 3; 


    public enum GameState{
        JOUE, NUL, CERCLE_ROUGE_GAGNE, CERCLE_BLEU_GAGNE
    }

    private GameState actualState;


    public enum Token{
        VIDE, CERCLE_ROUGE, CERCLE_BLEU
    }

    private Token actualPlayer; 


    private Token[][] board; 
    private final DrawCanvas canvas;
    private JLabel statusBar;
    private JLabel indexIndicator;



    public Pha(){

        canvas = new DrawCanvas(); 
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(canvasWidth, canvasHeight));


        canvas.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();

        int selectedRow = y / cellSize;
        int selectedCol;
            selectedCol = x / cellSize;


        if(actualState == GameState.JOUE){
            if(selectedRow >= 0 && selectedRow < ROWS && selectedCol >= 0
                    && selectedCol < COLS &&
                    board[selectedRow][selectedCol] == Token.VIDE){
                board[selectedRow][selectedCol] = actualPlayer;
                actualiseJeu(actualPlayer, selectedRow, selectedCol); 
                actualPlayer = (actualPlayer == Token.CERCLE_BLEU)? Token.CERCLE_ROUGE : Token.CERCLE_BLEU;
            }
        } else { 
            initGame(); 
        }

        repaint(); 
    }

  });




    statusBar = new JLabel("  ");
    statusBar.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG_INPUT, Font.ITALIC, 15));
    statusBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 5, 4, 5));


    Container cp = getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    cp.add(canvas, BorderLayout.EAST);
    cp.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack(); 
    setTitle("Pha par esQmo");
    setVisible(true);

    board = new Token[ROWS][COLS];
    initGame();  
}

    public void initGame(){
        for(int ligne = 0; ligne < ROWS; ++ligne){
            for(int colonne = 0; colonne < COLS; ++colonne){
                board[ligne][colonne] = Token.VIDE;
            }
        }
        actualState = GameState.JOUE;
        actualPlayer = Token.CERCLE_ROUGE;
    }

    public void updateGame(Token theSeed, int ligneSelectionnee, int colonneSelectionnee) {
      if (aGagne(theSeed, ligneSelectionnee, colonneSelectionnee)) { 
         actualState= (theSeed == Token.CERCLE_ROUGE) ? GameState.CERCLE_ROUGE_GAGNE : GameState.CERCLE_BLEU_GAGNE;
      } else if (estNul()) {  
         actualState = GameState.CERCLE_BLEU_GAGNE;
      }

   }
 public boolean estNul() {

      return false; 
   }

       (rowSelected, colSelected) */
   public boolean aGagne(Token theSeed, int ligneSelectionnee, int colonneSelectionnee) {
      return false; 

      /* (planche[ligneSelectionnee][colonneSelectionnee] == Jeton.CERCLE_BLEU  
            && planche[ligneSelectionnee][colonneSelectionnee - 1] == Jeton.CERCLE_BLEU
            && planche[ligneSelectionnee][colonneSelectionnee + 1] == Jeton.CERCLE_BLEU
       || planche[ligneSelectionnee - 1][colonneSelectionnee] == Jeton.CERCLE_BLEU      
            && planche[1][colonneSelectionnee] == theSeed 
            && planche[2][colonneSelectionnee] == theSeed
       || ligneSelectionnee == colonneSelectionnee            
            && planche[0][0] == theSeed
            && planche[1][1] == theSeed
            && planche[2][2] == theSeed
       || ligneSelectionnee + colonneSelectionnee == 2 
            && planche[0][2] == theSeed
            && planche[1][1] == theSeed
            && planche[2][0] == theSeed);*/


}

class DrawCanvas extends JPanel{

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ 
            super.paintComponent(g); 
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);


            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            for(int ligne = 1; ligne < ROWS; ++ligne){
                g.fillRoundRect(0, cellSize * ligne - halfGridWidth, canvasWidth - 1,
                        gridWidth, gridWidth, gridWidth);
            }
            for(int colonne = 1; colonne < COLS; ++colonne){
                g.fillRoundRect(cellSize * colonne - halfGridWidth, 0
                        , gridWidth, canvasHeight - 1,
                        gridWidth, gridWidth);
            }


            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(symbolStrokeWidth,
                    BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND)); 
            for(int ligne = 0; ligne < ROWS; ++ligne){
                for(int colonne = 0; colonne < COLS; ++colonne){
                    int x1 = colonne * cellSize + cellPadding;
                    int y1 = ligne * cellSize + cellPadding;

                    if(board[ligne][colonne] == Token.CERCLE_ROUGE){
                        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                        g2d.drawOval(x1, y1, symbolSize, symbolSize);
                        g2d.fillOval(x1, y1, symbolSize, symbolSize);
                    } else
                        if(board[ligne][colonne] == Token.CERCLE_BLEU){
                            int x2 = colonne * cellSize + cellPadding;
                            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                            g2d.drawOval(x1, y1, symbolSize, symbolSize);
                            g2d.fillOval(x2, y1, symbolSize, symbolSize);
                        }
                }

            }

            if(actualState == GameState.JOUE){
                if(actualPlayer == Token.CERCLE_ROUGE){
                    statusBar.setText("ROUGE, c'est votre tour");
                    statusBar.setForeground(Color.RED);

                } else {
                    statusBar.setText("BLEU, c'est votre tour");
                    statusBar.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                    statusBar.addMouseMotionListener(null);
                }
            } else
                if(actualState == GameState.NUL){
                    statusBar.setForeground(Color.yellow);
                    statusBar.setText("Match nul! Cliquez pour rejouer");
                } else
                    if(actualState == GameState.CERCLE_ROUGE_GAGNE){
                        statusBar.setText("Le jouer X a remporté la partie, cliquez pour rejouer");
                        statusBar.setForeground(Color.RED);
                    } else
                        if(actualState == GameState.CERCLE_BLEU_GAGNE){
                            statusBar.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                            statusBar.setText("Le joueur O a remporté la partie, cliquez pour rejouer");
                        }
        }
    } 


    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            Pha pha = new Pha();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make the effort to post copilable code. Consider [MCVE]

Comment: @c0der my code compile well. Did you get any error?

Comment: Yes. `actualiseJeu(actualPlayer, selectedRow, selectedCol); ` does not compile, and this one of course  `(rowSelected, colSelected) */`

Comment: Weird, I have no problem here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
//col , row : representing the cell you want to find neighbors to 
private void neighbours(int  col, int row) {

     //find all serouding cell by adding +/- 1 to col and row 
    for (int colNum = col - 1 ; colNum <= (col + 1) ; colNum +=1  ) {

        for (int rowNum = row - 1 ; rowNum <= (row + 1) ; rowNum +=1  ) {

             //if not the center cell 
            if(! ((colNum == col) && (rowNum == row))) {

                //make sure it is within  grid
                if(withinGrid (colNum, rowNum)) {
                    System.out.println("Neighbor of "+ col+ " "+ row + " - " + colNum +" " + rowNum );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

 //define if cell represented by colNum, rowNum is inside grid
//function used by neighbours()
private boolean withinGrid(int colNum, int rowNum) {

    if((colNum < 0) || (rowNum <0) ) {
        return false;    //false if row or col are negative
    }
    if((colNum >= COLS) || (rowNum >= ROWS)) {
        return false;    //false if row or col are > 75
    }
    return true;
}
```

Don't hesitate to ask if the code isn't clear.

To test it with you code modify this block:

```
    if(actualState == GameState.JOUE){
        if((selectedRow >= 0) && (selectedRow < ROWS) && (selectedCol >= 0)
                && (selectedCol < COLS) &&
                (board[selectedRow][selectedCol] == Token.VIDE)){
            board[selectedRow][selectedCol] = actualPlayer;
            //actualiseJeu(actualPlayer, selectedRow, selectedCol);
            actualPlayer = (actualPlayer == Token.CERCLE_BLEU)? Token.CERCLE_ROUGE : Token.CERCLE_BLEU;

            //add this to call function : 
            neighbours(selectedCol, selectedRow);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like more explanations thanks

Comment: What are colNum and rowNum? Are they the actual cell from which the neighbours are found?

Comment: See my edit: I added comments and how to use with your code.

Comment: I can see the output on every click. But still a bit confused: When I click on an empty cell with only blank cells surrounding it, it prints neighbour of x,y - x+1,y+1

Comment: Why should it behave differently with empty (what ever that means) and non-empty cell ? You need to figure out what the code does, and modify it to your need

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't realise it check all cells surrounding the center cell. My apologies. My purpose is to check if the cell contains a "token". as my cell a fill by "token" on every click

Comment: See  `ennum Token{VIDE, CERCLE_ROUGE, CERCLE_BLEU}`

Comment: Is there a way to check​ if a cell is empty (Token.VIDE)  or contains Token.CERCLE_ROUGE, Token.CERCLE_BLEU ?

Comment: I'lI be happy to help with it, but I think this should be posted as another question. Preferably with [mcve].  I think the 2 answers here answer the original question of "Finding the neighbors of 2D array"

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I've created a new question, please could you have a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43824645/determinate-cells-contents-on-2d-grid

Answer (score 1):

To find the neighbors of `board[r][c]`:

```
for (int nr = Math.max(0, r - 1); nr <= Math.min(r + 1, board.length - 1); ++nr){
    for (int nc = Math.max(0, c - 1); nc <= Math.min(c + 1, board[0].length - 1); ++nc) {
        if (!(nr==r && nc==c))  {  // don't process board[r][c] itself
            // board[nr][nc] is one of board[r][c]'s neighbors
        }
    }
}
```