# Finding path depending on cells' value on 2D grid array

Tags: java, algorithm, swing, 2d, path-finding

I have a grid composed with JLabel. Each cell has 3 states:
    public enum Token{
    VIDE, CERCLE_ROUGE, CERCLE_BLEU
    }
An empty cell == Token.VIDE

I have this simple algorithm that find all neighbors of a given cell then I use swing custom painting to draw a polygon following the path having the center of the label as points.

```
private CellsList getNeighbors(int  row, int col) {
    CellsList neighbors = new CellsList();
    for (int colNum = col - 1 ; colNum <= (col + 1) ; colNum +=1  ) {
        for (int rowNum = row - 1 ; rowNum <= (row + 1) ; rowNum +=1  ) {
            if(!((colNum == col) && (rowNum == row))) {
                if(withinGrid (rowNum, colNum )  ) {
                    neighbors.add( new int[] {rowNum, colNum});
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return neighbors;
}
```

here is the condition to have a path:

```
if((size() >= MIN_PATH_LEGTH) && neighbors.contains(origin)  ) {
            add(cell);
            return true;
        }
```

Now I want to make it more precise by adding conditions such as a path can be valid if only there are at least 4 cells with the same value found in the neighborhood AND at least one opposite value.

Example:
Red cells at **(11, 10)(10, 11)(11, 12)(12, 11)** can form a valid path if only there is at least a Blue cell at **(11, 11)**. (See image below)

[image]

And the following can't be a valid path, so no drawing:

[image]

For now, the algorith finds a path only with the minimal value (`int MIN_PATH_LEGTH = 3`)  I've defined but I can't find a way to define the second condition (*at least one opposite cell value within the neighborhood*)

I'll edit with new elements if needed.

Comment: I would use an approach somewhat similar to what @cladlink suggeted: after finding a path, find how many relevant cells are enclosed in it. If none, ignore it.

Comment: Yes his approach seems to be close, but it is covering only on type of token. and we'll need also diagonals

Comment: But I'm thinking about another approach: On click, each cell have to check its neighbourhood. if it finds an opposite cell, check if there is a like cell, if so, check if it forms a path, if true enclose the opposite token inside

Comment: I don't quiet follow your approach. What I suggest is a not too complicated algorithm to find **all** tokens enclosed by a path.

Comment: I admit my approach is a bit complicated.

Comment: Okay, so if Token.VIDE os enclosed by a path, that means no valid path, no drawing. Yeah seems legit.

Comment: So it only needs some coding  now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is based on the code posted in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43875184/3992939).

**Path class**

Add `isWithinLoop` to check if a cell is within path by checking if it has a 
path-cell to its left, right, top and bottom.

Also add `getContainedWithin` which returns a collection of all cells that are bounded by the path, and their token is of the opposite color of the path

```
    //returns a collection of all cells that are bounded by the path 
    //and their token is of the opposite color of the path 
    List<int[]> getContainedWithin() {

        //find path max and min X values, max and min Y values
        minPathRow = grid[0].length; //set min to the largest possible value
        maxPathCol = grid.length;
        maxPathRow = 0;              //set max to the largest possible value
        maxPathCol = 0;

        //find the actual min max x y values of the path
        for (int[] cell : this) {
            minPathRow = Math.min(minPathRow, cell[0]);
            minPathCol = Math.min(minPathCol, cell[1]);
            maxPathRow = Math.max(maxPathRow, cell[0]);
            maxPathCol = Math.max(maxPathCol, cell[1]);
        }

        //todo remove after testing
        System.out.println("x range: "+minPathRow + "-" 
        + maxPathRow + " y range: " + minPathCol + "-" + maxPathCol);

        List<int[]> block = new ArrayList<>(25);
        int[] cell = get(0);//get an arbitrary cell in the path
        Token pathToken = grid[cell[0]][cell[1]]; //keep a reference to its token

        //iterate over all cells within path x, y limits
        for (int col = minPathCol; col < (maxPathCol); col++) {

            for (int row = minPathRow; row < (maxPathRow); row++) {

                //check cell color
                Token token = grid[row][col];
                if ((token == pathToken) || (token == Token.VIDE)) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (isWithinLoop(row,col)) {
                    block.add(new int[] {row, col});
                }
            }
        }

        return block;
    }

    //check if row, col represent a cell with in path by checking if it has a 
    //path-cell to its left, right, top and bottom 
    private boolean isWithinLoop(int row, int col) {

        if(  isPathCellOnLeft(row, col)
             &&
             isPathCellOnRight(row, col)
             &&
             isPathCellOnTop(row, col)
             &&
             isPathCellOnBottom(row, col)
          ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private boolean isPathCellOnLeft(int cellRow, int cellCol) {

        for ( int col = minPathCol; col < cellCol ; col++) {

            if(getPath().contains(new int[] {cellRow, col})) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private boolean isPathCellOnRight(int cellRow, int cellCol) {

        for ( int col = cellCol; col <= maxPathCol ; col++) {

            if(getPath().contains(new int[] {cellRow, col})) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private boolean isPathCellOnTop(int cellRow, int cellCol) {

        for ( int row =minPathRow; row < cellRow ; row++) {

            if(getPath().contains(new int[] {row, cellCol})) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private boolean isPathCellOnBottom(int cellRow, int cellCol) {

        for ( int row = cellRow; row <= maxPathRow; row++) {

            if(getPath().contains(new int[] {row, cellCol})) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**Model class**

Add a getter method to access `getContainedWithin`:

```
List<int[]> getContainedWithin() {

    return (path == null ) ? null : path.getContainedWithin();
}
```

**Control class**

Update `ModelListener` to ignore a path if `getContainedWithin` is empty:

```
private class ModelListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            IndexedPropertyChangeEvent iEvt = (IndexedPropertyChangeEvent)evt;
            int index = iEvt.getIndex();
            int row = index / Model.COLS;
            int col = index % Model.COLS;
            Token token = (Token) evt.getNewValue();

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    view.setCell(token, row, col);
                    CellsList path = model.getPath();
                    //ignore path if null, empty or encloses no cell
                    if((path == null) || path.isEmpty()
                                        || model.getContainedWithin().isEmpty()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    view.addPath(path);
                    view.refresh();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The complete code can be downloaded for this [repo](https://bitbucket.org/c0derepo/pha).

Comment: Have a question: how do I express: `if a token is contained, exclude it from forming a path?` I would like to exclude all contained tokens so that no path can be established with other tokens. Something like this. http://prntscr.com/fa74hj (the red token has been contained first, so the red cannot form a path)

Comment: This requirement means that previous paths affect path calculations. It can be achieved in many ways like a. have a static collection of contained cells in path b. deeper and maybe better change have a Cell class, which has attributes like row, col,token. contained etc and use it to represent cell (rather than just int[]{row, col}  ).  It better be posted as a new question.

Comment: I'll post one as soon as possible

Comment: I've  asked a question here, tried to explain what I want to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44093010/invalidate-an-element-forming-a-path-if-it-is-surrounded

Comment: Hi, long time no see. What's up?

Comment: Is there somewhere else we can connect other than on SO? I would like to ask some questions. If you don't mind of course

Comment: A chat  room here I guess. In general  I prefer to do it here, so others can contribute as well, and others can benefit for the dialogue.

Answer (score 2):

test before calling this method if the redCell's path OK:

```
public boolean isThereABlueCellWithinMyRedPath() {
    // height = height of your map
    // width = width of yout map
    // this array is suppose to be in an other place...
    Cell[][] cellArray = new Cell[height][width];
    // ... so are those two lists
    List<Cell> blueCellsList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Cell> redCellsList = new ArrayList<>();

    //foreach blueCell on the map ...
    for (Cell blueCell : blueCellsList) {
        boolean north = false;
        boolean east = false;
        boolean south = false;
        boolean west = false;
        int originX = blueCell.getX();
        int originY = blueCell.getY();

        // ... if there is a redCell at north...
        for (int i = originY; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (redCellsList.contains(cellArray[originX][i])) {
                north = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // ... East ...
        for (int i = originX; i < cellArray[originX].length; i++) {
            if (redCellsList.contains(cellArray[i][originY])) {
                east = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // ... South ...
        for (int i = originY; i < cellArray.length; i++) {
            if (redCellsList.contains(cellArray[originX][i])) {
                south = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // ... West ...
        for (int i = originX; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (redCellsList.contains(cellArray[i][originY])) {
                west = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // ... I am surrended by redCell
        if (south && east && north && west)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I did not try the code but it seems to work.

Comment: Oh great, but didn't you consider diagonals?

Comment: if the shape of the red path can be set freely the algorythm is more complex. I think 'A Star' may help you :
[http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html](http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html)
You have to check the direct neighbour of the blueCell and then the neighbour of the neighbours etc.

When the neighboor is a wall you stop the research, when you can't search anymore you're surrouded.

Go to "Breadth First Search" part and clic on the square to surround the star.
[https://snag.gy/bQy9mu.jpg](https://snag.gy/bQy9mu.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can make a list of blue cells and redcells and if you want to test if a there's a blue cell within the red cell's path you:

go to NORTH until you meet a redCell or a map limit : if it 's a map limit you test with the next blueCell, else you go back to your position and do the same for EAST, SOUTH, WEST.
If on the 4 sides you find a redCell first, you return true else you return false.

It can be enough if you want to test in a quite small map. But if the shape made by the red cell can be free I don't find a better way.